# How to show private data in macOS unified log

Tags: macos, security, logging, macos-catalina

I need to debug some problems regarding user login, but many somehow interesting information in the new unified log are hidden, like this (shortened):

```
opendirectoryd[130]: [com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] queuing request - <private>
```

On some older macOS versions, there was an option to enable the logging of private data:

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
```

However, on Catalina, this results in:

```
log: Invalid Modes 'private_data:on'
```

So, question is: How to enable the logging of private data on macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As described here [Unified Logs: How to Enable Private Data](https://www.cmdsec.com/unified-logs-enable-private-data/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) you can create and install a configuration profile like this:

> ### Profile to enable (reveal) private data
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>   <key>PayloadContent</key>
>   <array>
>     <dict>
>       <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
>       <string>ManagedClient logging</string>
>       <key>PayloadEnabled</key>
>       <true/>
>       <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
>       <string>com.apple.logging.ManagedClient.1</string>
>       <key>PayloadType</key>
>       <string>com.apple.system.logging</string>
>       <key>PayloadUUID</key>
>       <string>ED5DE307-A5FC-434F-AD88-187677F02222</string>
>       <key>PayloadVersion</key>
>       <integer>1</integer>
>       <key>System</key>
>       <dict>
>         <key>Enable-Private-Data</key>
>         <true/>
>       </dict>
>     </dict>
>   </array>
>   <key>PayloadDescription</key>
>   <string>Enable Unified Log Private Data logging</string>
>   <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
>   <string>Enable Unified Log Private Data</string>
>   <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
>   <string>C510208B-AD6E-4121-A945-E397B61CACCF</string>
>   <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
>   <false/>
>   <key>PayloadScope</key>
>   <string>System</string>
>   <key>PayloadType</key>
>   <string>Configuration</string>
>   <key>PayloadUUID</key>
>   <string>D30C25BD-E0C1-44C8-830A-964F27DAD4BA</string>
>   <key>PayloadVersion</key>
>   <integer>1</integer>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

Save the file as *YourProfileName.mobileconfig*.  If you don't need to sign it or deploy it you can just double-click and as a `.mobileconfig` it will automatically add to *Profiles* in *System Preferences* once you authenticate.

[image: System Preferences]

Monitoring unlocking *Users and Groups* in *System Preferences* on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 with (as suggested in the linked article) this command gives the following results:

> ```
> sudo log stream --predicate '(subsystem == "com.apple.opendirectoryd") && (senderImagePath == "\/System\/Library\/OpenDirectory\/Modules\/PlistFile.bundle\/Contents\/MacOS\/PlistFile")'
> ```

- Without profile loaded `<private>` data (in this case the user unlocking) is redacted:
  [image: Without profile loaded]
- With the profile loaded the previous `<private>` data is visible:
  [image: With profile loaded]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. In fact, I read the linked article, but to be honest, I was totally scared by the need to sign it with an MDM tool. Seems to be only necessary in case you actually use an MDM tool for remote deployment.

Comment: As a complement, this still works on macOS Big Sur (January 2022)

Comment: Still works on macOS Monterey (12.3) (May 2022)

Comment: This still works in macOS 13.2.1 (Ventura). To confirm installation of the profile, open System Settings, click Privacy & Security in the left-side column, then scroll all the way to the bottom on the right side to find Profiles. In Profiles, double-click the “Enable Unified Log Private Data” item to install it.

Comment: doesn't work on 13.6