# How to show private data in macOS unified log within Xcode

Tags: macos, security, logging, xcode, macos-ventura

I am getting runtime errors in Xcode involving interface builder. However, the system logger is sanitizing pertinent information contained in the logging.

```
Unknown class <private> in Interface Builder file at path <private>.
```

The system logger's sanitation of private data renders some logging useless, both in the Console.app and within Xcode.

Older versions of macOS had ways to enable the logging of private data (pre-Catalina):

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
```

And (post-Catalina):

[In Console.app, how can I reveal to what  tags are actually referring?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311578/in-console-app-how-can-i-reveal-to-what-private-tags-are-actually-referring?noredirect=1&lq=1)

These mechanisms, which work with earlier systems, don't work with macOS 13.6.

My question is: How do you enable the logging of private data on macOS 13.6 and later?